# View javascript console on any website for tons of end users?

Tags: javascript, logs

Are there any tools/services/code that will let me load up any website in possibly hundreds of browers from remote locations, and view the messages that were logged to the javascript console for each browser?

For example, imagine something like BrowserShots that would take a picture of a website in tons of different browsers, and would also show the javascript console in the picture, or save it to a dumped a log file.

I'd like to do this for both websites I control, and website I have no control over, e.g. google.com or any site at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I found was that https://webpagetest.org allows you to capture remote javascript console output when running a test.

This NPM package available at the command line goes into more detail:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpagetest